# SQL multiple joins on the same table

Tags: sql, join

So i have a table dpgift. I need to generate 24 different "stats" (counts and sums with filters) based on the table.

The below should generate the first three columns.

```
select a.lc as listCode, a.c, NVL(b.c,0), NVL(c.c,0)
    FROM (select list_code as lc, count(donor) as c
              FROM dpgift 
              group by list_code) a
        LEFT JOIN (select list_code as lc, count(donor) as c
                       FROM dpgift
                       WHERE dpgift.rectype="P" 
                       group by list_code) b
        LEFT JOIN (select list_code as lc, count(donor) as c
                       FROM dpgift
                       WHERE dpgift.rectype="G" 
                       group by list_code) c
            ON b.lc = c.lc 
            ON a.lc = b.lc
```

This almost works but something is wrong with my joins. The third column (c.c), only has values where b.c is not null.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

btw, i'm working in VFP but sql seems to work pretty standard.

edit: ok here's the output i'm getting

```
listcode  c    exp_3 Exp_4
482       14   0     0
483       2    0     0
499       852  1     857
....
```

It should be:

```
listcode  c    exp_3 Exp_4
482       14   0     14
483       2    0     2
499       852  1     857
....
```

Comment: How does it not work? What output are you getting and what do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version should produce what you're looking for.

```
SELECT list_code,
       COUNT(donor),
       SUM(CASE WHEN rectype = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rectype = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gcount
    FROM dpgift
    GROUP BY list_code
```

Comment: Awesome. I had to use vfp's `iif()` instead of `case when` cause vfp is fugly, but otherwise it works great, thanks.